# Custom object not visible to Admin creating Data Cloud Data Stream

Tags: datacloud, data-streams

In my Data Cloud Trial Org I wanted to create a new Data Stream via the Salesforce CRM connector to a Custom Object existing in the same org. But it doesn't show up there.

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

I double-checked all the required things:

1. Admin sees the object

[image]

2. Admin has See All on it

[image]

3. Admin has this Data Cloud Permset assigned

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the Admin user that's controlling the visible entities for selection - it's the `Platform Integration User`, which is a hidden System user. It's assigned the `Data Cloud Salesforce Connector` permission set which you'll want to update (you can see this in `Manage Assignments` of permission set).

As a result, you'll want to update the [Data Cloud Salesforce Connector](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_enable_user_permissions_external_salesforce_org.htm&type=5) permission set to include view all access to your custom object and then you should see it for selection in data streams

[image]